# How to get the Icon size from the marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the Icon size of the marker, here the below code, It returning the title and icon name is perfectly returning. But the icon size is not returning, Please help how to get the Icon size from the marker.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapinfo[index][6], mapinfo[index][7]),

icon: '<?=bloginfo('url').$logo ?>',

map: map,

scrollwheel:false,

streetViewControl:true,

title:  $title

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the icon you need to use the `getIcon()` method from your `marker` object - then access the `size` attribute.

```
marker.getIcon().size.toString()
```

This will return `(width, height)` (in pixels).

**EDIT: Setting a marker icon size**

To set the size of your marker you'll need to define the size using the `scaledSize` attribute in our icon options when you specify it in your marker options. `scaledSize` will scale your icon down to the dimensions you specify, while `size` option will cut the image based on the dimensions you provide (this is useful if you have sprite images for icons). See below on how to set up a marker with custom icons properly:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

  position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapinfo[index][6], mapinfo[index][7]),

  icon: {
    url : '<?=bloginfo('url').$logo ?>',
    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50,50)
  },

  map: map,

  scrollwheel:false,

  streetViewControl:true,

  title:  $title

});
```

The thing to note here is that the maps API, uses it's own `size` object to determine size's of marker icons.

References:

- [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)
- [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)
- [Size](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size)

Comment: wait, I don't think I understood your question..did you perhaps mean you can't **set** the icon size?

Comment: i need to size icon in 50*50 px if i upload icon that have 100 * 100

Comment: ok, I understand now - take a look at the update to the answer, and hopefully that solves your problem